# how double parantheses ()() workes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here i have a question regarding Double parentheses, can anyone please explain me how does it works.

```js
function counter() {
  console.log("hI");
  return function (){
    console.log("inside hI");
  }
}    
counter()();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `counter` returns a function, so having parentheses after the call to `counter` calls the function that `counter` returns

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Oliver, can you provide me any document regarding this topic, wanted to study more on this topic.

Comment: @SanthoshAcharya Google `IIFE`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney ya sure I wil do it. Thank you.